# Magento 2 - how do I add multiple shipping methods with custom logic, without paying for a shipping extension?

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to add the following shipping methods:

A price for sending an item:

- to the home country
- to the home country (priority)
- to the EU
- to the EU (priority)
- to every other country
- to every other country (priority)

As far as I know that can't be done out of the box with magento 2.
I also tried looking for a free extension to do that, but couldn't find any. Because I don't want to pay for one, I'd love to add that functionality with code on my own, so my question is:

**Which files do I have to tamper in Magento 2, to add the logic from above (in a future proof way)?**

Thanks

ps: If there's a free extension I didn't find, please let me know

ps2: The shipping company prices I'll be using all depend on weight btw, so I may need to add a formula in my code as well

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming, even though you are asking for code. To be about programming your question should contain the code that you're asking about. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I'm asking for code, so it's a coding related question.

Comment: https://github.com/magepal/magento2-custom-shipping-rate

Comment: https://github.com/rakeshmagento/magento2-shipping-per-product

Comment: @SudoPlz - This isn't about solving a problem with code you have. It's asking us to write your code or provide an extension. Both of those things are off-topic here.

Comment: I'm not asking you to write my code, I'm asking you to point me to the correct files, thanks.